# Row wise top 3 maximum values IN TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Question input:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
--  --  --  --  --  --
A    1   5  10   7   9
B   11  12  30   5   4
C    5   6   7   2  20
D    3   5   4   1   2
```

Expected output:

```
A   C4  C6  C5      
B   C4  C3  C2      
C   C6  C4  C3      
D   C3  C4  C2
```

Finding the three maximum values in each row.

Comment: Shouting gets you nowhere, shown effort gets you answers.

Comment: @HoneyBadger is right. Try using http://sqlfiddle.com/ to demonstrate what you've done

Comment: Also tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: And PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT AT US

Comment: Ask proper question using ? marks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a proper way to taking help of someone. Explain what you have tried and write last line in small letter. Capital letter shows that you are shouting

Comment: Hi guys,please help me to solve the above task.I am using MSSQL SERVER 2012 version.the question is how to find the first three maximum values of each row in a table.In table columns are fixed.

Comment: @chaituchaitanyareddy...If you want help you'll first have to address the issues mentioned in the comments. Repeating the 'question' is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

This solution first uses UNPIVOT to turn the columns to rows.

And ROW_NUMBER to get a number for the order based on the value.

Then PIVOT is used on that row_number to get the top 3 columns.

```sql
-- using a table variable to demonstrate
declare @T table (c1 varchar(1), c2 int, c3 int, c4 int, c5 int, c6 int);

-- test data
insert into @T (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
('A', 1, 5, 10, 7, 9),
('B', 11, 12, 30, 5, 4),
('C', 5, 6, 7, 2, 20),
('D', 3, 5, 4, 1, 2);

select c1, [1] as Max1, [2] as Max2, [3] as Max3
from
(
    select 
    c1, upper(col) as col, 
    row_number() over (partition by c1 order by val desc, col) as rn
    from @T t
    unpivot (val for col in (c2, c3, c4, c5, c6)) up
) q
pivot (max(col) for rn in ([1],[2],[3])) as p
```

Results :

```
c1  Max1 Max2 Max3
A   C4   C6   C5
B   C4   C3   C2
C   C6   C4   C3
D   C3   C4   C2
```